# Bootstrap navbar search to send search query to Flask view

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have a base.html wherein the navigation bar has a search box.

```
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action={{ url_for('search') }} method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="search" type="search" placeholder="Search Storage Request" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
```

Here is the view:

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    query = request.args['search']
    req_search = Storage.query.filter_by(req_no=query)
    return render_template('search.html', req_search=req_search)
```

But when I searched anything from the navigation bar search box. Here is the error I get:

```
query = request.args['search']
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'args'
```

Somehow I am not able to grab the search query in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in general, search requests are performed with `GET` method and you don't even need to mention `method="GET"` since it's the default method. Also you don't need the `csrf_token` in your form since it's a `GET` request.`

so i suggest you those fixes in

#### your template

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{{ url_for('search') }}">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="search" type="search" placeholder="Search Storage Request" aria-label="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

#### your view function

```
@app.route('/search')  # 'GET' is the default method, you don't need to mention it explicitly
def search():

    # query = request.args['search']
    query = request.GET.get('search')  # try this instead

    req_search = Storage.query.filter_by(req_no=query)
    return render_template('search.html', req_search=req_search)
```

Comment: Thanks cizario, you are write. I changed it to GET. Also, I was doing one more silly mistake. I had defined a function with python keyword "request" mistakenly. Now the app works perfectly.