# Flask form not validating with HTML

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I've tried looking through the documentation and other posts on here, though I'm still having trouble.

**views.py**

```
@bp.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@bp.route('/newSearch', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def newSearch():
    form = NewSearchForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # DB code
        return redirect(url_for('newPage.html'))
    return render_template('newSearch.html', form=form)
```

Once the user enters a search query and clicks "submit" it should redirect to the results page. However, It's not validating the form correctly with my current form tag.

**index.html**

```
<form action="{{ url_for('newSearch') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">    
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Search"></input>
</form
```

The button lives in the index.html. It fails to redirect to `newPage.html` in the case above. What is missing that's causing it to fail validation? any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your form knows why it failed to validate. After calling `form.validate_on_submit()`, you can inspect `form.errors` to see why validation failed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65757488/bootstrap-navbar-search-to-send-search-query-to-flask-view

Comment: If it is rendering `newSearch` page, then there must be an issue with form validation.

Comment: @noslenkwah I did not know about printing form errors and now I see why, thank you!